# FatalExecutionEngineError with MySQLConnector/Net

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio-2010

I'm developing a C#.NET application that connects to a MySQL DB and uses some unsafe code to be able to use an old C++ dll.

As soon as the program starts, it will load the dll and allocate a pointer, it will then initialize some C# variables, then delete the pointer.

In the program I have a dialog which has a tab control within. The constructor of this "dialog" fetches data from the variables initialized with the old dll and from the DB and here start the problems:

```
        Dictionary<String, int> dizUM;
        MySqlCommand            myCom;
        MySqlConnection         myConn;
        MySqlDataReader         myRead;

        cmbRigheCons.Items.Add( MosaicoS.Properties.Resources.STR_CONS_DESC_GEN );
        cmbRigheCons.Items.Add( MosaicoS.Properties.Resources.STR_CONS_TIP_SOTT );
        cmbRigheCons.Items.Add( MosaicoS.Properties.Resources.STR_CONS_SOTT );
        cmbRigheCons.Items.Add( MosaicoS.Properties.Resources.STR_CONS_NOM_PEZ_CONS );
        cmbRigheCons.SelectedIndex = MosaicoMain.CFG.DescCons;
        cmbRigheVarMat.Items.Add( MosaicoS.Properties.Resources.STR_CONS_DESC_GEN );
        cmbRigheVarMat.Items.Add( MosaicoS.Properties.Resources.STR_CONS_TIP_SOTT );
        cmbRigheVarMat.Items.Add( MosaicoS.Properties.Resources.STR_CONS_SOTT );
        cmbRigheVarMat.Items.Add( MosaicoS.Properties.Resources.STR_CONS_NOM_PEZ_CONS );
        cmbRigheVarMat.Items.Add( MosaicoS.Properties.Resources.STR_CONS_NOM_PEZ_NEL_CONS );
        cmbRigheVarMat.SelectedIndex = MosaicoMain.CFG.DescVarMat;
        try
        {
            string connessione;

            connessione = MosaicoMain.CFG.DBConnection.Replace( "Option=3;", "" );
            connessione = connessione.Replace( "Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver};", "" );
            myConn = new MySqlConnection( connessione );
            myCom = new MySqlCommand();
            myConn.Open();
            myCom.Connection = myConn;
            myCom.CommandText = @"SELECT umi_id, umi_um FROM unimis WHERE umi_tipoum = 0 ORDER BY umi_um;";
            myRead = myCom.ExecuteReader();
            dizUM = new Dictionary<String, int>();
            while( myRead.Read() )
                dizUM.Add( myRead.GetString( 1 ), myRead.GetInt32( 0 ) );
            cmbUMSup.DataSource = new BindingSource( dizUM, null );
            cmbUMSup.DisplayMember = "Key";
            cmbUMSup.ValueMember = "Value";
            myRead.Close();
            myConn.Close();
        }
        catch( MySqlException mySqlException )
        {
            MessageBox.Show( mySqlException.ToString() );
        }
```

Here if I comment from myConn.Open(); to myConn.Close(); I've got no troubles, but opening the connection results in an almost immediate program crash **WHEN I SWITCH BETWEEN TABLES**, but NOT in this part of program but in:

```
    private void configurazioniToolStripMenuItem1_Click( object sender, EventArgs e )
    {
        try
        {
            frmConfig = new FrmConfigurazioni();
            frmConfig.ShowDialog();
        }
        catch( Exception exception )
        {
            MessageBox.Show( exception.ToString() );
        }
    }
```

which is where I load the previous code snippet.
The error is:

```
Managed Debugging Assistant 'FatalExecutionEngineError' has detected a problem in 
'C:\DEVELOP\MosaicoS\MosaicoS\bin\Debug\MosaicoS.vshost.exe'.
Additional Information: The runtime has encountered a fatal error. 
The address of the error was at 0x792380d9, on thread 0x824. 
The error code is 0xc0000005. 
This error may be a bug in the CLR or in the unsafe or non-verifiable portions of user code. 
Common sources of this bug include user marshaling errors for COM-interop or PInvoke, which may corrupt the stack.
```

and it is **NOT** an exception. If I comment the code, I don't get the crash, also, if I try to connect with the same string to the same database in another solution, I've got no problems.
How can I solve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'0xc0000005' is Access Violation exception. It is difficult to do find out what is wrong from the code you have provided. I would suggest to find the source code of that old c++ dll and debug them together in one solution. You can debug c++ dll from .net by checking the "Enable unmanaged code debugging" check box under the Debug section in your .net project properties.

Comment: Well, technically the dll is no more used at the time of crash. Moreover, I do not have access to dll source code and it works almost perfectly in MFC C++ enviroment. Anyway, I'll try with that unmanaged code debugging.

Comment: I've edited the question, please, take note of the change. Does it help if I post the Call Stack?

Comment: As you pointed out: '0xc0000005'is an access violation exception. I found out where the problem is generated, even if actually I don't know how to solve it. Thank you.

Comment: @IssamTP Where was the problem generated? I've been hitting the same issue and have no ideas left